# Postgres : Deadlock with 2 update queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to wrap my head around with this deadlock issue in our production, and now i really need some help.

> PostgreSQL 9.5.10

Query 1: (Updating 1000 records)

```
update entitlements.stream_general sg
set stream_offset_id =nextval( 'entitlements.stream_general_stream_offset_id_seq' ),
should_update_offset_id = false
from (select id, topic, stream_id from entitlements.stream_general where should_update_offset_id = true limit 1000) sg2
where sg.id=sg2.id and sg.topic=sg2.topic and sg.stream_id = sg2.stream_id
```

Query 2: (Updating a single record)

```
update entitlements.stream_general set stream_action = $1::entitlements.stream_action_type, update_dt = now(), should_update_offset_id = true where stream_id = $2 and topic = $3 and id = $4
```

Exception :

> Process 60563 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3603536083; blocked
>   by process 60701. Process 60701 waits for ShareLock on transaction
>   3603536039; blocked by process 60563.

Since there are only two transactions involved in the deadlock processes, how can one Update can be in deadlock with another Update. According to my understanding, after first Update there will be RowExclusiveLock on all those rows, and second Update should get blocked. How can there be a DEADLOCK?

`stream_general` table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE entitlements.stream_general (
    stream_id int4 NOT NULL,
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    topic varchar NOT NULL,
    stream_offset_id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1'::integer,
    create_dt timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    update_dt timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    stream_action stream_action_type NOT NULL,
    should_update_offset_id bool NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (stream_id, topic, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (stream_id) REFERENCES entitlements.stream(stream_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;
CREATE INDEX stream_general_id_idx ON entitlements.stream_general USING btree (id, topic) ;
CREATE INDEX stream_general_should_update_offset_id_index ON entitlements.stream_general USING btree (should_update_offset_id) ;
CREATE INDEX stream_general_stream_id_idx ON entitlements.stream_general USING btree (stream_id, topic, stream_offset_id) ;
```

> Note : stream_id is the foreign key.

Only culprit i can think of is subquery in Query1, but how i am not able to figure out how that Select can be problematic. Or may be something is up with foreign constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is first taking a read lock before taking a write lock.  Could that cause a deadlock when the second query waits for a write lock too?

Try [`for update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) to have the subquery acquire a write lock?

```
update  ...
from    (
        select  ...
        from    ...
        FOR UPDATE
        ) sg2
```

Comment: yes using `for update` was my first thought. But until i am not sure what is causing the deadlock, i don't want to go ahead with the fix. Also, your suggested query is wrong as we cant use LIMIT in UPDATE query.

Comment: Right, suggested query removed.